# -[UITextField drawPlaceholderInRect:] not getting called

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I'm developing an application where there should be a suggestion to the user and he may accept or discard it. For now let's say that i just want to display the suggestion to the user.

I'm using `drawTextInRect:` and `drawPlaceholderInRect:`.

`drawTextInRect:` works as it is supposed to, but `drawPlaceholderInRect:` only gets called twice: first when the text field first appears, and then when I click inside it. After that, I guess it caches the result and doesn't call `drawPlaceholderinRect:` ever again.

Here's the example code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>    
#import "CustomTextField.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet CustomTextField *field1;

@end
```

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.field1.suggestionText = @"abcde";
}

- (IBAction)toggleSuggesting:(id)sender {
    self.field1.suggesting = !self.field1.isSuggesting;
    [self.field1 setNeedsDisplay];
}

@end
```

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomTextField : UITextField

@property(assign,nonatomic,getter=isRequired) BOOL required;
@property(assign,nonatomic,getter=isSuggesting) BOOL suggesting;
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSString* suggestionText;

@end
```

```
#import "CustomTextField.h"

@implementation CustomTextField

-(void)drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    if ( _suggesting && [self.suggestionText length] > 0 ) {
        [self drawSuggestionInRect:rect];
    }
    else {
        [super drawPlaceholderInRect:rect];
    }
}

-(void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    if ( _suggesting && [self.suggestionText length] > 0 ) {
        [self drawSuggestionInRect:rect];
    }
    else {
        [super drawTextInRect:rect];
    }
}

-(void)drawSuggestionInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [[UIColor greenColor] setFill];
    [self.suggestionText drawInRect:rect withFont:self.font];
}
@end
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. Click on the text field
2. Change field1.suggesting to true
3. click on the text field and dismiss the keyboard
4. the text shown in the textfield should be green "abcde"